# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error: Adapter 'http' is not available in the build

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, axios, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to use axios in React chrome extension module, but I am facing this issue.

**Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error: Adapter 'http' is not available in the build**

```
// background.ts

import axios from "axios"
...
axios.get<SerInyResponse>("https://realtor.p.rapidapi.com/locations/v2/auto-complete")
            .then(response => {
                this.Storage.setLocalStorage(response.data).then( (re) => {
                    resolve(response.data.Listeners)
                })
                
            })
            .catch( err => {
                reject(new Error(err))
            })
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If this is inside the service worker I guess you can't use axios because it's based on XMLHttpRequest. Simply use `fetch` instead.

Comment: Good idea, i already turned into fetch function. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Write with Fetch

`const res = await fetch(url, { method: "GET", credentials: "include", headers: { Cookie: token }, });`

Answer (score 5):

service workers only support fetch